# Showing that Galois group of extension of degree $n$ is divisible by $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I know that for any Galois extension $K/F$ of degree $n$ for a separable irreducible polynomial $f(x)$, we have that the Galois group embeds into $S_n$. But I want to show that this group is divisible by $n$.

Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ be the distinct roots of $f(x)$ in $K$.

Then I want to apply the tower law somehow, but I don't see how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is of degree $n$ and is irreducible over $F[x]$, then $[F(\alpha_1):F] = n$.

So $$[K:F] = [K:F(\alpha_1)][F(\alpha_1):F]$$
The order of the Galois group is just $[K:F]$.

Comment: How do we know that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$ is of degree $n$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7   What is your original assumption? Is $K$ is a splitting field of a degree $n$ separable irreducible polynomial over $F$?

Comment: Oh yeah, never mind. Thanks.